# Watson Conversation Service - Quit Parameter for Slots/ Entities

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson, watson-conversation

There is a new feature in the conversation service where you can define slots/ entities for specific intents to extract the relevant information from the user input like currencies or specific string inputs. Those slots can be set mandatory in case you need them to proceed and the user will be asked for missing slots until he provides them.

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to define sth. like quit parameter so I can easily interrupt this conversation? The general documentation does not provide any information regarding this problem.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/entities.html#defining-entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding node-level handler which will listen to your cancellation intent and fill the slots with dummy values.

You can read more about this approach in the documentation: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-build.html (paragraph "Handle requests to exit the process")

Comment: just a warning about using such handlers: your 'cancellation' intent won't be recognized unless one of your slots is *not* filled in.